# How can I "use" a mysql cell from the previous row of the current row, and display all rows including the first row, in one SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have an HTML table with dynamically added content that **needs** to look like this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID |          A          |          B          |            C             | Elapsed since last checkout |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 2018-09-01 00:00:00 | 2018-09-03 00:00:00 | 2 days 0 hours 0 minutes | unknown                     |
|  2 | 2018-09-05 00:00:00 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00 | 1 days 0 hours 0 minutes | 2 days 0 hours              |
|  3 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00 | 2018-09-08 00:00:00 | 2 days 0 hours 0 minutes | 0 days 0 hours              |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Columns A and B are added into the table through a form. Columns C and "Elapsed..." are calculations depending on the values from the **previous and current** rows.

When I try to output the table data into HTML from Php/MySql, this is what I'm getting:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID |          A          |          B          |            C             | Elapsed since last checkout |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  2 | 2018-09-05 00:00:00 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00 | 1 days 0 hours 0 minutes | 2 days 0 hours              |
|  3 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00 | 2018-09-08 00:00:00 | 2 days 0 hours 0 minutes | 0 days 0 hours              |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'm using the logic from this question: [How to get next/previous record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql) to make up my SQL statement to get a value from within the previous row *of the current row*, but unfortunately the first row is not being displayed:

```
"SELECT * FROM (select * from bookings WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS x ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
```

**How can I display *all* the rows from the database *and* select a mysql cell from the *previous row of the current row* in one SQL statement?**

This is my full code if you need to skim through it. I am using nested queries because I have no idea how else to do it... (I read about `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` but according to my understanding that is only if you are using different tables, which is not the case for me.)

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM bookings";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $out = $row['check_out'];
        $in = $row['check_in'];
        $sum = $row['sum'];

        $sqlQueryLastDate = "SELECT * FROM (select * from bookings WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS x ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
        $resultLastDate = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQueryLastDate);
        $resultCheckLastDate = mysqli_num_rows($resultLastDate);
        if ($resultCheckLastDate > 0) {
            while ($rowLastDate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultLastDate)) {
                $lastInDate = $rowLastDate['check_in'];
                //echo "previous row's in date:" .$lastInDate;

                $sqlQueryCurrentDate = "SELECT * FROM (select * from bookings WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS x ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
                $resultCurrentDate = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQueryCurrentDate);
                $resultCheckCurrentDate = mysqli_num_rows($resultCurrentDate);
                if ($resultCheckCurrentDate > 0) {
                    while ($rowCurrentDate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCurrentDate)) {
                        $currentOutDate = $rowCurrentDate['check_out'];
                        //echo "current row's out date:" .$currentOutDate;

                        $lastIn = new DateTime($lastInDate);
                        $currentOut = new DateTime($currentOutDate);
                        $intervalLastCurrent = $lastIn->diff($currentOut);
                        $elapsedLastCurrent = $intervalLastCurrent->format('%a days %h hours');
                        echo "
                                <tr>    
                                    <td>".$id."</td>
                                    <td>".$out."</td>
                                    <td>".$in."</td>
                                    <td>".$sum."</td>
                                    <td>".$elapsedLastCurrent."</td> 
                                </tr>
                            ";
                    } /*$sqlQueryCurrentDate*/
                }
            } /*$sqlQueryLastDate*/
        }
    } /*$sqlQuery*/
}

?>
```

Even if you can just provide me with the necessary terminology to get this to work, I would do my own research. For example, someone suggested I used a `LEFT JOIN` but after looking into it found it was not ideal for what I want to achieve here.

Things I have tried to implement and couldn't get right:

[How can I subtract a previous row in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560829/how-can-i-subtract-a-previous-row-in-sql)

[SQL Previous row from the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022505/sql-previous-row-from-the-same-column)

(And more)

Comment: "I read about JOIN and LEFT JOIN but according to my understanding that is only if you are using different tables" - No, you can always do Self-Join (using JOIN)

Comment: I see...Can the `SELF JOIN` clause apply to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, for sure. try to figure out.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. I'll come back if it didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to solve this is with window functions which are available only in MySQL 8

Without window functions you can use something like the following query:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  (SELECT value FROM bookings WHERE id < b.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) AS prev 
FROM 
  bookings b 
ORDER BY id;
```